# What is C# 6.0 #pragma disable warnings feature?

Tags: c#

The list of [C# 6.0 final features](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Languages-features-in-C%23-6-and-VB-14) contains a feature called #pragma listed as "Added" and the example is to disable warnings. However this feature [did exist in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys.aspx) before 6.0. What exactly was added in 6.0?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Previously, you had to specify the warning *number*. So to disable CS0501, you'd use

```
#pragma warning disable 0501
```

Now, you can use

```
#pragma warning disable CS0501
```

... which is incredibly important when you've got Roslyn Code Analyzers raising warnings with different identifiers. It's basically changed the namespace of warnings from "digits" to "alphanumeric strings".

I don't know the details of the new grammar - I haven't seen a C# 6 spec yet - but the old grammar was:

*warning-list*:
  *decimal-digits*
 *warning-list* *whitespace<sub>opt</sub>* `,` *whitespace<sub>opt</sub>* *decimal-digits*

Comment: Basically before you could only disable CS-prefixed warnings?

Comment: @Stilgar: Yup, as far as I'm aware. Those were the only ones the *compiler* even knew about, of course - anything else came from a different tool chain, whereas in Roslyn it's all done *through* the compiler.